# How to join a table to itself with a like and a full outer join

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with four columns: Company, CompanyNumber, Team, IsActive, Volume
where IsActive is either 0 or 1. The numbers are randomly assigned.

Most companies will have two types of entry in the table, one type for the volume of active employees (IsActive = 0), one type for the volume of inactive employees (IsActive = 1). In such cases, the Company entry for the inactive employees will be something along the lines of "ex-employees of " and the name of the company. Some, however, will be "ex employees of " (no hyphen), or another variation. In still other cases the Company fields will match exactly, ie the Company in the inactive employees entry will be the same as the Company in the active employees entry.

The team names will be the same across the isactive = 0 and isactive = 1 records.

Not all companies will have an entry for active employees, and not all companies will have an entry for inactive employees.

All I need to do is identify the matching active and inactive entries for each company and team and add the volumes, returning this against the value in the Company field for the active entry, or, if there is no active entry, the value in the Company field for the name for the inactive entry.

I tried

```
select coalesce(a.company,b.company) as company
,coalesce(a.team,b.team) as team
,sum(isnull(a.Volume,0) + isnull(b.Volume,0))
from tblA a
full outer join tblA b
on b.company like '%' + a.company
and a.team = b.team
and b.isactive = 1
where a.isactive = 0
group by coalesce(a.company,b.company)
,coalesce(a.team,b.team)
```

but I am not returning the companies that don't have any isactive = 0 entries.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did the answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Your where clause automatically excludes all companies that don't have an Active row:

```
where a.isactive = 0
```

Update...  As I thought of your comment, I realized that wouldn't work.  You might try this for the WHERE clause.  This **should** return results that have always have the IsActive = 1 on the left and IsActive = 0 on the right, but also accounting for nulls.

```
select coalesce(a.company,b.company) as company
    ,coalesce(a.team,b.team) as team
    ,sum(isnull(a.Volume,0) + isnull(b.Volume,0))
from tblA a
full outer join tblA b
    on b.company like '%' + a.company
        and a.team = b.team
        and b.isactive = 1
where ((a.isactive = 1) OR (a.isactive IS NULL))
    AND ((b.isactive = 0) OR (b.isactive IS NULL))
group by coalesce(a.company,b.company)
,coalesce(a.team,b.team)
```

Comment: Will 
    `where a.isactive != b.isactive`
not then duplicate records, meaning I count the volume for each record twice, once when I bring it from the left version of the table, once from the right?

Comment: And I thought joining with 
    `on b.company like '%' + a.company`
would deal with the need to worry about anything like 
    `REPLACE(REPLACE (a.companyname, 'ex employees of', ''), 'ex-employees of', '')`
esdpecially as there are many different ways 'ex employees' has been typed, with just a hyphen, with just a space, with a space before and after the hyphen, or just before, or just after, or other combinations I haven't spotted.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but no. With the code as you have suggested the output is no different to the original code. I tried moving your suggested where clause to the join instead, but that duplicated things. I think I may have to just use the original code with a union to get in the rest, as that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted this with a work around - keeping the code as I wrote it above, then unioning it with a query that just returns the missing data. If anyone wants to come up with a neater solution, feel free.